# when and why to use multiple NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, core-data

Basically, I have only used one moc in my app, but I think I should use multiple NSManagedObjectContext in some cases.

1. when I should use multiple NSManagedObjectContext?
2. I have heard that I should use 3 moc in some cases, but I don't know which cases I should use 3 moc?

Comment: The only reason I can think of would be if you had distinct sets of data you might want to access independently.

Answer (score 17):

Typically, you want to use a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread that will access the Core Data db. This is to prevent the object graphs from potentially getting into an inconsistent state due to concurrent writes to the same context.

The simplest way to handle this is to create a new `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread and share a single `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Create a property in your AppDelegate of type `NSManagedObjectContext` and override the getter to return a new context for each calling thread. Do this by utilizing the `threadDictionary` of each thread.

First, set up your managedObjectModel and persistentStoreCoordinator as you normally would. Then create your context in your AppDelegate and assign to your property:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.storeCoordinator;
```

In your managedObjectContext getter override, use the following code to return a separate context for each calling thread:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSThread *thisThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if (thisThread == [NSThread mainThread])
    {
        //For the Main thread just return default context iVar      
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    else
    {
        //Return separate MOC for each new thread        
        NSManagedObjectContext *threadManagedObjectContext = [[thisThread threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"MOC_KEY"];
        if (threadManagedObjectContext == nil)
        {
            threadManagedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [threadManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [self storeCoordinator]];
            [[thisThread threadDictionary] setObject:threadManagedObjectContext forKey:@"MOC_KEY"];

        }

        return threadManagedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Now anywhere in your code where you access the managedObjectContext property of the AppDelegate, you will be sure to be thread safe.

Comment: What would be best way to maintain "MOC_KEY"  uniquely for each NSThread?

Comment: @ParthAdroja, I had the same confusion. But you see the "threadDictionary" is an object property. It means it will be separate for each thread.So you can save the MOC with same key in each thread's dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Following link clearly explains when, why and how to use Multiple managed object context.

> http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Following are two main reasons to use multiple managed object context.

- To make `NSManagedObjectContext` thread safe, because `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe.
- Lock the `NSManagedObjectContext` to display data on UI. It means that when you are displaying data on UI and also fetching data from server, we should fetch data on child `NSManagedObjectContext` to avoid concurrency and UI blockage issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use different "moc" for different threads

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

for the "unity of work" enterprise pattern aka you can rollback your multiple chances - as long they're not saved (and then merged back to the main context)

ofc also for background updates and so on