# Asynchronous fetch vs multiple managed object context core data which is preferable?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, core-data

I am confused when to use
 1) Asynchronous fetch
 2) multiple managed object context
in core data while fetching large number of records, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Aysnch fetch when you are remotely pulling data. Since that data pull will take time (if on main thread) your app will freeze until it has got the requested data. The user will think that the app froze and nothing is happening when in reality it is fetching data to display.

You would use multiple managed object context when you have to modify data in your core data data base. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596330/4933540) for more.

You do the first one for your network requests and second one when modifying data in your database managed by core data.

Comment: In that case I can use batch update for modifying data in database, is there any advantage of multiple managed object context over batch update?

Comment: I'll answer you other way round. Apple recommends to only use batch update feature if the traditional approach( load every single record into memory, update the record, and send the changes to the persistent store. If the number of records is too large, iOS will simply bail out due to a lack of resources.) is too resource or time intensive. If you need to mark hundreds or thousands of email messages as read, then batch update is the best solution.